# Should I create two different gulp tasks?

Tags: javascript, gulp, workflow, frontend

This is a pretty general question - but as a newcomer to taskrunners I'm a little confused about the workflow.  I understand that you can create a task that does things like uglify and minify but what about debugging while you write the code? Specifically, if I need to view my js source to identify issues, what would be my workflow?  Do I create a different task that doesn't effect my javascript files for developing, then run the task that does everything when I know things are working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer in context of the parts of your workflow you hint at but don't mention, but for uglification/minification one good solution would be sourcemaps, or more specifically, since you're asking about gulp: [`gulp-sourcemaps`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps).

From their docs:

```
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(plugin1())
      .pipe(plugin2())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Those plugins (`plugin1`, etc) would be things like uglify, but do need to be sourcemaps-compatible.

All this allows your browser to find its way back from concatenated, minified code, all the way to the correct source files.

As a footnote, the alternative you already mention can also work okay: compose your build tasks in a way that you can serve source (or at least: unminified) files in development, and provide minified code in staging and production.

As with all such (somewhat) broad questions: it depends.